# I received an email that says someone sent me bitcoin

Tags: blockchain

I was sent bitcoin through email, but I am being told to pay a fee first so that I can receive the funds. What should I do and I don't have the fees?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a scam. Receiving bitcoins does not require paying fees.

If you are not otherwise expecting this payment, then you can safely just ignore the message. It is spam.

Answer (score 0):

You should never trust people who promise you money in exchange for more money.

Ignore and delete the mail.